# Compiletime check to see if function-template is instantiated

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, compile-time, compile-time-type-checking

Is there a possibility to check at compile-time if a function of a class-template or a free template-function is instantiated throughout the code of a specific TU?

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    inline static void f() {}
};
template<typename U>
void g() {}

int main() {
     A<int>::f();
}

static_assert(some_check_v<A>); // for A<int>::f() -> ok
static assert(some_check_v<...>); // g<int>() -> nok
```

Something like the above?

The purpose should be to prevent the user from missing a specific call to a function.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179835/compile-time-template-instantiation-check

Comment: I don't understand. How is this not just putting it in a `requires` expression/`concept`?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is somewhat deprecated by the introduction of concepts in newer versions of C++, if you're stuck on an older version, this should do the job for free template funtions:

```
template<typename Type_T>
constexpr int MyFunction() = delete; //The function

template<>
constexpr int MyFunction<bool>() //A specialisation for bool
{
    return 1;
}
```

```
//The type traits
namespace Internal 
{ 
    template<typename Type_T, typename = void> 
    struct IsMyFunctionImplemented : std::false_type 
    { }; 
    
    template<typename Type_T> 
    struct IsMyFunctionImplemented<Type_T
        , std::void_t<decltype(MyFunction<Type_T>())>
        > : std::true_type 
    { }; 
} 
template<typename Type_T> 
inline constexpr bool IsMyFunctionImplemented_v = Internal::IsMyFunctionImplemented<Type_T>::value;
```

Usage:

```
IsMyFunctionImplemented_v<bool>; //returns true
IsMyFunctionImplemented_v<float>; //returns false
```

Working example here:
https://godbolt.org/z/qGn5WGGrc

**Note that the default implementation for the function template has to be declared as deleted, otherwise this will not work!**

This is because any call towards `MyFunction<Type_T>()` is allowed if there is a default implementation, and thus the expression `std::void_t<decltype(MyFunction<Type_T>())>` does not equate to `void` because `decltype(MyFunction<Type_T>())` provides a valid function signature.

Also note that this only validates the function name and arguments, not its return type, if this is important to you, you'll need to make some modifications, here's a great example for member functions:
[Check if a class has a member function of a given signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-of-a-given-signature)