# Collect instantiated template types at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, typelist

Consider this snippet:

```
struct A {

  template <typename T> void bar(const T &) {
    /*
    I would like to write something like:
        if constexpr(type T already processed/T is already present in typelist)
        ...do something fancy
        else if constexpr(type T not processed/T is not present in typelist)
    */
  }
};

struct Msg1 {};
struct Msg2 {};

int main() {
  A a;

  a.bar(Msg1{});
  a.bar(Msg1{});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8eW7aW5az)

Is it possible to see at compile time for which types the method `bar` was already instantiated?

Ideally, there would be some kind of growing `typelist`, where one can check at compile time for which types `bar` is already instantiated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179835/compile-time-template-instantiation-check However, I believe it is odr violation

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible without some form of compiler support. No single translation unit is aware of all other translation units, and by link time every constant expression and every type has to be fixed.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: That makes sense. I am not allowed to use "hacks", so I guess even with c++17 I am out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not possible to do so at compile time. However, it would be possible to do the following at runtime:

```
#include <typeindex>
#include <type_traits>
#include <unordered_set>
struct A {
    private:
    std::unordered_set<std::type_index> already_processed_ts;
    public:
    template<typename T>
    void bar(const T&){
        if(already_processed_ts.find(typeid(T)) != already_processed_ts.end())
            std::cout << "Already processed " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
        else{
            already_processed_ts.insert(typeid(T));
            std::cout << "Processing " << typeid(T).name() << "... \n";
        }
    }
}
struct Msg{};
int main()
{
    f(Msg{}); // Prints "Processing 3Msg..." (at least on my compiler)
    f(Msg{}); // Prints "Already processed 3Msg"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thx for your suggestion! Too bad we cannot rely on this, since it is costly at runtime.